# Laravel API and Vue SPA or inline Vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

When working with Laravel, it seems I can use Vue inside the Laravel Blade but I can also use Laravel project only as an API while using another project (Vue in this case) as a front-end connecting to the API?

Which approach is better and has its advantages/disadvantages?

Comment: If you're going to run it on the cloud, you can use APIs in any way. You can also use it if you are going to work in your local. I would recommend combining backend and frontend, so it is always a nuisance to execute two separate projects.

Comment: if you use vuejs separably then it will be good for debugging because in laravel after vuejs is ruining after compiled  so all error is showing in app.js and in other hand vujes as separate error will show exact line and path . so   better to use separately